# NSMutableArray not populating

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, insert, nsmutablearray

I have a simple NSMutableArray which I am trying to store a few objects in. However in NSLog, the contents of the array always comes as null... I just dont understand why. Here is my code:

In my header file:

```
NSMutableArray *dataFiles;
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
dataFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Later on in my code in a method which is trying to add a string to my NSMutableArray:

```
[dataFiles insertObject:url atIndex:0]; // 'url' is an an NSURL.
```

What am I doing wrong? This is always how I have used NSMutableArray's, why are they all of a sudden not working?

**UPDATE**

I did indeed do an NSLog on the "url" (NSURL) before its being added to the array and it is not null at all. Here is the output:

```
THE URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E991FAFC-80DB-437B-B214-96720B1AA7AF/Documents/19Feb15_072308am.aif
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just tried @Dheeraj Singh solution and it did not work:

```
        if ([dataFiles count] == 0) {
            [dataFiles addObject:url];
        }

        else {
            [dataFiles insertObject:url atIndex:0];
        }

        NSLog(@"data in: %@", dataFiles);
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Post your PreCode before:[dataFiles insertObject:url atIndex:0];

Comment: Could you please print the variables dataFiles and url right before [dataFiles insertObject:url atIndex:0]; as well

Comment: Before inserting in to array please see your dataFiles and url in NSLog in console.

Comment: @ashForIos I have updated my question with this. But the url is not the problem, it is not null before it is being used to populate the array.

Comment: Ok.Just put a hardcoded url like "stackoverflow.com" and after that also if u get nil response, then its much better to clean your code or either restart your machine.

Comment: @ashForIos Ok I will try that now.

Comment: your code seem to be correct just clean the project by command+shift+k.no need to check condition it always return 0 count while allocating array so you can insert a object at index 0.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff just check in your method if your array is not initialized and not nil.

Comment: what you are doing is working perfectly with me. **I strongly feel you have NSArray and not NSMutableArray**

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine `dataFiles` at the point where you are going to insert the URL - chances are it is `nil`

Comment: Check out my answer, do you understand why it works??? I have got a little further now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong, but below (your) code is working fine with me.

```
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *murl = @"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E991FAFC-80DB-437B-B214-96720B1AA7AF/Documents/19Feb15_072308am.aif";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:murl];
[arr insertObject:url atIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Array is %@",arr);
```

### Output

```
Array is (
    "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E991FAFC-80DB-437B-B214-96720B1AA7AF/Documents/19Feb15_072308am.aif"
)
```

***What I strongly feel is you are using NSArray against NSMutableArray. Please confirm the same.***

Could you post the actual code so that we can tell you what is going on?

Comment: No I defined it as an NSMutableArray in my header file.

Comment: Check out my answer, do you understand why it works??? I have got a little further now.

Comment: Thanks you were correct in the end. The reason I was getting this issue, is that I was populating my NSMutableArray with the NSUserDefaults which only returns immutable arrays. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of playing around I found out what was "wrong" or at least what is stopping my code from working. It is because before I was initialising the NSMutableArray in the viewDidLoad method. As soon as I moved the NSMutableArray initialisation code to method where I wanted to write the data to it, it started working. Anyone know why?? Here is my code now:

```
        // Initialise the audio arrays.
        // Originally this line was in the viewDidLoad.
        dataFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if ([dataFiles count] == 0) {
            [dataFiles addObject:url];
        }

        else {
            [dataFiles insertObject:url atIndex:0];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do in Following way :

```
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *url = @"www.test.com";
[arr addObject:url];
NSLog(@"Count of Array is %i",[arr count]);

*** if you want to add multiple items then you can do by following way
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
    [arr addObject:@"Hello"];

}
NSLog(@"Count of array is %i",[arr count]);
```

Comment: While the code works it does not solve the OP's problem - and it is the opposite of the OP's desired behaviour - it adds objects to the end of the array rather than adding them to the beginning.